# Add Volley and Gson to Library Jar

Tags: android, android-studio, gson, android-volley

I have volley and gson Jars in my library project. I want to create Jar and add these two library as part of my Jar. I have found few links but how can I use them. I am using `./gradlew makeJar` to make jar of my library project

http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/

Comment: "I want to create Jar and add these two library as part of my Jar" -- why? This is generally considered to be a bad idea, as you make things more difficult for consumers of your JAR.

Comment: I am working on library for android projects. I want to make things easier for user who is integrating my library. So I want these jar to be part of my library.

Comment: "I want to make things easier for user who is integrating my library" -- you are making it harder for the user who is integrating your library, because now they cannot control what version of Volley and Gson that they use. Also, you are making it harder on people like me who wind up having to answer questions about why your library does not work with newer versions of Volley and Gson. You are using Android Studio, so please publish your JAR as an artifact with dependency information. This achieves much of your objective while offering greater flexibility.

Comment: It make sense, thanks alot for your help. Can you please answer one more question. If I publish my jar with dependency would my library code still be private or anyone can access it?

Comment: If you only publish the compiled JAR, people will only have access to the compiled JAR.

Comment: Is there any way I can make few classes available to user in jar and hide all others. One way is to remove access modifier from class and it will accessible in that package. But in my library I have different packages and they can access each other. (I like to view different packages as different folders simply which allows me to structure the code in a good way). You help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72927/discussion-between-nauman-afzaal-and-commonsware).

Answer (score 1):

If you add a dependency on the gradle file and compile a jar of that lib the dependencies will be added to that jar as a sub-dependency.

It's actually the best way to do it, because if the users of your library has the same dependency it will not duplicate dependencies.